# Changing Action Bar color with hex color

Tags: java, android, interface, colors, android-actionbar

I want to change the color of the action bar
the problem is that color changes to white instead of purple, anyone know why is that?

```
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0x3F48CC));
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Specify the alpha value, `0xFF3F48CC` or use `Color.parseColor("#3F48CC")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adneal comment fixed it

Specify the alpha value, 0xFF3F48CC or use `Color.parseColor("#3F48CC")`

thanks